# Function to determine what color shirt somebody should wear to a football game depending on what seat they have

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I was tasked with writing a function to find what color shirt someone should wear to our college football game depending on what seat they sit in. Here is the function I came up with:

```
function getColor(section, row) {
  const colorA = "orange";
  const colorB = "white";
  section = section.toUpperCase();

  /* Case 1: Section is a special section */
  if (section.includes("TER") || section.includes("WC") || section.includes("EC")) {
    /* Numbers in special sections are guaranteed to be single digit,
       So just grab the last character in the section. */
    const number = section.slice(-1);
    // Even numbers are colorB, odd are colorA
    return (number % 2 === 0) ? colorB : colorA;
  }
  /* Case 2: Section is a single letter (No numbers) */
  else if  (section.length === 1) {
    /* A through Q have different row numbers than R through W */
    const section_divider = getSectionDivider(section);

    /* Odd-lettered (A, C, etc.) sections are colorA when above
       the section divider. Even-lettered section are colorB when
       above the section divider. */
    if (section.charCodeAt(0) % 2 === 0) {
      return (row >= section_divider) ? colorB : colorA;
    } else {
      return (row >= section_divider) ? colorA : colorB;
    }
  }
  /* Case 3: Section is two letters (No numbers) */
  else if (section.length == 2 && section.charAt(0) >= 'A' && section.charAt(0) <= 'Z'  &&
           section.charAt(1) >= 'A' && section.charAt(1) <= 'Z') {
    /* Double lettered sections are always the same color as the
       single letter's bottom row */
    return getColor(section.charAt(0), 0);
  }
  /* Case 4: Section is a single letter followed by a number */
  else if (!isNaN(section.slice(1))) {
    /* Row is WC */
    if (isNaN(row)) {
      /* WC rows should just match the section below them */
      return getColor(section, 0);
    }

    /* X3 and Z15 are special cases where the whole section isn't one
       color. They are both colorB above the section divider and colorA below. */
    if (section === "X3" || section === "Z15") {
      const section_divider = 16; // Just in case it changes in the future.
      return (row <= section_divider) ? colorA : colorB;
    } else {
      /* This is the number. (i.e. X4 => 4, Z13 => 13) */
      const number_in_section = parseInt(section.slice(1));
      return (number_in_section % 2 === 0) ? colorA : colorB;
    }
  }
  /* Case 5: Section is a double letter followed by a number */
  else {
    /* Double-letter-number sections are always the opposite of the
       single-letter version of its self's top row.
       (i.e. XX13 is whatever X13's top row isn't) */
    return getColor(section.slice(1), 1000) === colorA ? colorB : colorA;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way of solving this problem? Is the code clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 points where you can work to increase the quality of your code.

1. simplify some conditions check
2. get rid of comments

**simplify some conditions check**

Consider the following code:

```
/* Case 3: Section is two letters (No numbers) */
else if (section.length == 2 && section.charAt(0) >= 'A' && section.charAt(0) <= 'Z'  &&
       section.charAt(1) >= 'A' && section.charAt(1) <= 'Z') {
```

I think you could make it shorter with just a regular expression:

```
else if (section.match(^[A-Z]{2}$)) {
```

It is not just short and fast to read, but, in this case, it show you what is the "rule" that the string should satisfy.

**get rid of comments**

Your code is full of comments, and that made it difficult to reed.

Consider that many developer, me included, don't trust the comments and read it just when something weird happened. And in this case too there are very few times the comments helps.

The reason is you should update the comments as you update the code, but this never happened as it is more work and you don't have time.

Compilers or interpeter never care the comments.

The other point is that the developers could read and understand the code, and your effort should put in made the code readable for human beings.

Let me show some examples.

```
  /* Case 1: Section is a special section */
  if (section.includes("TER") || section.includes("WC") || section.includes("EC")) {
```

Consider the followhing change. As you can see you don't need the comment any more.

```
if (isASpecialSection(section)) {

...

function isASpecialSection(section) {
    return section.includes("TER") || section.includes("WC") || section.includes("EC");
}
```

Another example:

```
/* Case 2: Section is a single letter (No numbers) */
else if  (section.length === 1) {
```

Even the condition is short, you should use the same approach, as it is not clear in which case you are here.

Look at the comment, it "lied", because you just check that the string have length 1, not that is only letters. Maybe you don't have the case today, but data could change.

So remove the comment and change the check:

```
else if (section.match(/^[A-Z]$/)) {
```

Not all comments are bad, you should avoid those comments that tell what the code does, because you can read the code and so it is a waste of time for the developers that read your code.

Too many comments like in your code make difficult to read the code.
To put all those comments you break the indentation.

Try to make your code more readable by using proper names or functions to encapsulate complex conditions.

Naming is hard and take time, I know, but it pay back.

Comment: Thanks for all of the great advice! Also, the validation on the input happens before it is ever passed into this function, so checking if the length is 1 is sufficient for making sure it is a single letter in this context.  Would the code be more clear if the regexes were variables and instead had statements like `else if (section.match(singleLetter)) {`?  Thanks for the descriptive feedback!

Comment: Using variables with proper names for regular expression will of course increase the readability.

Answer (score 1):

### Spaghetti

When I see this type of code I instantly cringe, not because the code is bad, apart from too much noise the code is good. I cringe because I have done this type of thing a zillion times and have learnt that if you are reliant on a outside uncontrolled data source (namely the section string and row numbering) that source will change, have exceptions, be buggy and generally just be a SOB.

You will hear about the need to change your code when the client sees buggy software, not good software bad input and you need to fix it now!

Your code is a complicated mix of if statements that will not easily accept change. Change requires time to write, test, and deploy. Complicated code like this is hard to change as the data format will not have considered your careful design. So the changes adds more if statements inside your heavily statement laced code, making the next change even more complicated.

So a better design is a modular approch.

#### RegExp

If you have never used the [RegExp Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) before it is well worth learning. There are many sites that provide a live testing interface. [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) is but one.

#### Modular

Going through your code I saw that all the various section formats could be tested for via a RegExp, the only parts that needed custom code were the extraction of the seat colour from that section row data.

I thus create an array of objects that store the regular expression, and the conversion function.

```
// example module 
const secDesc = {
    match : /TER|WC|EC/g ,
    color() { return section.slice(-1) % 2 ? colorA : colorB },
},
```

You can then tests the section string and if there is a match call the conversion function.

```
if (secDesc.match.test(section)) { return secDesc.color() }
```

Your matching process is reliant on order to make matches, so i have done the same, but ideally it should be able to do it in any order such that each section would be independently matched and converted to colour without having to have failed a previous match.

#### Noise

Before the rewrite I will point out the only other bad point about your code, too much noise. Noise is code that is redundant, or superfluous, and text/comments that does not add to what is in the code and is in code making a mess when it should be else where out of the way.

- **Comments**. You description of the section formats is mostly redundant, I actually read none of it in any detail, and did not need it for the rewrite.

  You are writing as if the person reading the comment does not know how to code, this person will never be reading your code in the first place, if they are they should not be.

  A brief description of the format at the top of the source fill as a reference is all that is needed.

  A great quote (that I can not remember the source of) is *"Comments are just a lie waiting to happen."* This is very true for code that is modified, you seldom read you own comments, they become almost invisible to your eye, when you change your code chances are you do not update the comments and no compiler or parser is going to give a hoot about what the comments say, The only people that are going to read your comments are inexperienced coders, the very last people you want to confuse with a forgotten comment.
- **Compact** Every character adds complexity and the less is more. You use the  ternary expression appropriately (less noise than if statement) but you have not thoroughly thought them out.

You have for example

```
 return (number_in_section % 2 === 0) ? colorA : colorB;
```

But you can do the same with 6 characters less noise.

```
 return number_in_section % 2 ? colorB : colorA;
```

- **Redundant superfluous**. Creating variables that are used once is just noise and serves only to make the code harder to read, run, and change (if needed).

  See snippet below. The optimiser will likely never create the interim variable `number_in_section` and you only use it once and it is immediately out of scope, it is superfluous. You have also misused the function `parseInt`, the number is an Int and Javascript will coerce the string to a number for you, it is thus redundant.

.

```
 const number_in_section = parseInt(section.slice(1));
 return (number_in_section % 2 === 0) ? colorA : colorB;

 // becomes 
 return section.slice(1) % 2 ? colorB : colorA;
```

- **Implied else?** If you are returning, breaking, continuing, or throwing inside a condition block there is no need to have the block followed by a else statement, that else is implied.

You have

```
if (section.charCodeAt(0) % 2 === 0) {
  return (row >= section_divider) ? colorB : colorA;
} else {
  return (row >= section_divider) ? colorA : colorB;
}
```

Same with less noise

```
if (section.charCodeAt(0) % 2) {
    return row >= section_divider ? colorA : colorB;
}
return row >= section_divider ? colorB : colorA;
```

Or dare I compound the ternary, i find it much more pleasing to the eye. Warning some will not like this. Note that when you compound ternary expressions it is best to wrap sub expressions in (...) to clearly mark out each condition.

```
return section.charCodeAt(0) % 2 ?
    (row >= section_divider ? colorA : colorB) :
    (row >= section_divider ? colorB : colorA);
```

#### The rewrite

As there is missing code this code is untested and thus likely contains bugs due to typos and stupidity (on my part)

The compact version because I am pushing this style.

```
function getColor(section, row) { // Format note. Warning compound ternaries ahead
    var i;
    const colorA = "orange";
    const colorB = "white";
    const sections = [{
            match : /TER|WC|EC/i ,
            color() { return section.slice(-1) % 2 ? colorA : colorB }
        }, {
            match : /^.$/,  
            color() {
                return section.charCodeAt(0) % 2 ? 
                    (row >= getSectionDivider(section) ? colorA : colorB) :
                    (row >= getSectionDivider(section) ? colorB : colorA);
            }
        }, {
            match : /^[A-Z][A-Z]$/i,
            color() { return getColor(section.charAt(0), 0) }
        }, {
            match : /^[A-Z][0-9]+$/i,
            color() { 
                if (isNaN(row)) { return getColor(section, 0) }         
                return section === "X3" || section === "Z15" ? 
                    (row <= 16             ? colorA : colorB) :
                    (section.substr(1) % 2 ? colorB : colorA);
            }
        }, {  
            match : /./,
            color() { 
               return getColor(section.substr(1), 1000) === colorA ? colorB : colorA; 
            }
        }     
    ];
    i = 0;
    do {
        if (sections[i].match.test(section)) { return sections[i].color() }
    } while (++i < sections.length);
}
```

Ahh so sweet, no overflow fitting in the one panel, all functions should be like that.

And a more standard version if you are having trouble reading the above.

```
function getColor(section, row) {
    var i;
    const colorA = "orange";
    const colorB = "white";
    const sections = [{
            match : /TER|WC|EC/i,
            color() {
                return section.slice(-1) % 2 ? colorA : colorB;
            }
        }, {
            match : /^.$/,
            color() {
                if (section.charCodeAt(0) % 2) {
                    return row >= getSectionDivider(section) ? colorA : colorB;
                }
                return row >= getSectionDivider(section) ? colorB : colorA;
            }
        }, {
            match : /^[A-Z][A-Z]$/i,
            color() {
                return getColor(section.charAt(0), 0);
            }
        }, {
            match : /^[A-Z][0-9]+$/i,
            color() {
                if (isNaN(row)) {
                    return getColor(section, 0);
                }
                if (section === "X3" || section === "Z15") {
                    return row <= 16 ? colorA : colorB;
                }
                return section.substr(1) % 2 ? colorB : colorA;
            }
        }, {
            match : /./,
            color() {
                return getColor(section.substr(1), 1000) === colorA ? colorB : colorA;
            }
        }
    ];
    i = 0;
    do {
        if (sections[i].match.test(section)) {
            return sections[i].color();
        }
    } while (++i < sections.length);
}
```

Comment: Your `do … while` is a _weird_ way to write a `for` loop!

Comment: @200_success LOL but a `for` loop is weird way to write  a `do ... while` loop. `do ... while` is a lost art, so seldom seen yet in many cases the better option as they do one less comparison  If `sections` was an argument of the function with unknown possible zero length I would have used a `for` loop.

Comment: Here we are, doing complex computations like regex tests, in an interpreted language — and you're doing stuff like `var i = 0` at the top and `while (++i < sections.length)` at the bottom, just to save one comparison? `for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) { … }` is much more idiomatic and instantly recognizable. There's a reason why `do … while` is a lost art.

Comment: @200_success the initing `i` should be at the `while` loop, and the `toUpperCase` is in the wrong place, should be after all the variable declarations, or better not there as at all as regExp flag i will do the trick. The idiomatic argument assumes the reader is incompetent,  someone that should not be coding in the first place. The more we apply harm reduction to coding style the worse the problem becomes.